# Check if a query returns a blank cell and replace with 0

Tags: sql, ms-access, expressionbuilder

I've written a query in access and it returns a blank cell for most of the results, I need to replace these blank cells with a 0

The first way I tried was:

```
TtlSickDays: IIf([TotalSickDays]='',0,[TotalSickDays])
```

But I got the error message: Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Then I tried

```
TtlSickDays: CInt(IIf(Len([TotalSickDays])=0,0,[TotalSickDays]))
```

But then I got another error message: Invalid use of null

So I assumed the blank was returning 'Null'

so I tried:

```
TtlSickDays: CInt(IIf([TotalSickDays]=Null,0,[TotalSickDays]))
```

But got the same error message...

So I'm a little stumped on what else to try

I edit the bit of sql in an area like this:

[image]

Any help on the situation would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like that:

```
TtlSickDays: CInt(IIf(IsNull([TotalSickDays]),0,[TotalSickDays]))
```

[MS Access: IsNull Function](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/isnull.php)

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly! I had tried LEN and IsBlank but IsNull was what I needed, thanks a lot.

Comment: @Sythnet if it is the answer, would you please be so kind and mark it as one? thanks

Comment: Will do, because my question is still new, I have to wait 7 minutes before I can make it the answer (3 more minutes)

Comment: oh sry, i didn't knew that.